# How to model a relationship in EF Core when using custom table and field names

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I’m trying to model a relationship between two tables in an existing MsSQL Db using EF Core, but the Db has tables using custom table names and column names.

EF Core is failing to setup the relationship, even though I’m specifying the relationship using either attributes or FluentAPI.

**I think the problem is because I have non-convention names for tables and columns and EF is failing to setup the relationship properly.**

Here’s the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE paid_authors
(
    paid_author_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [name] varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE hardback_books
(
    hardback_book_id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    paid_author_id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    title varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO paid_authors VALUES ('duck' ,'Scrooge McDuck')
INSERT INTO hardback_books VALUES (NEWID(), 'duck', 'Duck Tales')
```

Here’s the C# modelling:

```
[Table("paid_authors")]
public class PaidAuthor
{        
    [Key]
    [Column("paid_author_id")]
    public string PaidAuthorId { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<HardbackBook> HardbackBooks { get; set; }
}

[Table("hardback_books")]
public class HardbackBook
{
    [Key]
    [Column("hardback_book_id")]
    public Guid HardbackBookId { get; set; }

    [Column("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HardbackBooks")] // This could be wrong!
    [Column("paid_author_id")]
    public string PaidAuthorId {get; set;}
}
```

My code:

```
foreach(var author in context.PaidAuthors.Take(10))
{
    // This next line makes it work, but it shouldn’t be needed!
    // author.HardbackBooks = context.HardbackBooks.Where(x => x.PaidAuthorId == author.PaidAuthorId).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(author.PaidAuthorId + " - " + author.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(author.HardbackBooks.Count);
}
```

When I run the code I get `System.NullReferenceException` and `author.HardbackBooks` is null.

I’ve tried FluentAPI, specifying the ForeignKey on the parent class... But there must be something obvious I’m missing! I'm happy to switch to FluentAPI if it can be made to work there.

Needless to say, I can't change the Db structure... :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can't leave the collection Navigation Property null, and should have an inverse Navigation Property on the book.  Something like:

```
[Table("paid_authors")]
public class PaidAuthor
{
    [Key]
    [Column("paid_author_id")]
    public string PaidAuthorId { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<HardbackBook> HardbackBooks { get; } = new HashSet<HardbackBook>();
}

[Table("hardback_books")]
public class HardbackBook
{
    [Key]
    [Column("hardback_book_id")]
    public Guid HardbackBookId { get; set; }

    [Column("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public PaidAuthor PaidAuthor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PaidAuthor")] 
    [Column("paid_author_id")]
    public string PaidAuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this doesn't work. All that happens is that the property is initialised to an empty list - it doesn't do the join in the Db to get the books for the authors.